# NextJs rewrites produce localhost redirected you too many times error

Tags: javascript, url-rewriting, next.js, backend

The following is my next.config.js:

```
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/results',
        destination: 'https://mywebsite.com/results',
      },
    ];
  },
};
```

According to Nextjs rewrites documentation (https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites#rewriting-to-an-external-url), upon visiting  https://nextjswebsite.com/results, the contents of the page should be rewritten with contents of https://mywebsite.com/results.

However, I end up getting "localhost redirected you too many times".

Any ideas what causes the error?

Comment: Are you sure the `destination` is different from your Next.js app URL?

Comment: @juliomalves i have nothing but a homepage at the nextJs app with one big button in the middle there's no other pages created yet

Answer (score 5):

so apparently i only needed a tailing slash at the destination

```
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/results',
        destination: 'https://mywebsite.com/results/',
      },
    ];
  },
};
```